# Is it normal for the Xamarin.Forms shared csproj file to reference the Xamarin.Mac and Xamarin.iOS framework?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, csproj, xamarin.mac

If I open my file I see:

```
<ItemGroup>
<Reference Include="Xamarin.Mac">
    <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\Library\Frameworks\Xamarin.Mac.framework\Versions\7.4.0.4\lib\reference\mobile\Xamarin.Mac.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>

<Reference Include="Xamarin.iOS">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\Library\Frameworks\Xamarin.iOS.framework\Versions\14.14.2.5\lib\mono\Xamarin.iOS\Xamarin.iOS.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Is this to be expected for the shared file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as various Xamarin.Forms native projects wouldn't compile if they refer to this project.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder what I did, or what could of happened, for those references to end up in the file?